# Building home on slab foundation on lot above natural spring

Tags: safety

We are towards the end of costruction on a new home in rural northeast georgia on a flat lot(slight slope towards the street) and as the electric company started digging to place the final wires they hit a natural spring.

The only additional drainage on the lot is a medium drainage pipe on the left side of the lot that connects directly to city drain on the street.

When it has not rained in a day the lot is dry overall up top but there is water present in most holes that are deeper than a foot.

My question is, could this still be a safe lot for the house with a water spring underneath the slab foundation?

Comment: It is a spring, or a marginal swamp, or a potential flood plain? Any of these would have me concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Before the home was built, there should have been site and soil surveys done.  The builder use the results of this surveys, to determine how to properly construct the foundation for the building. Assuming these surveys were done, and the engineer designed an appropriate foundation. There should be no danger to the structure.

However, if the water was not taken into consideration, then it could pose a risk to the home.

You should verify that all the proper planning was done, and that the water was considered in the building planning.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of soil is there? Clay could be a problem as it turns to jello from vibration. Good gravel that drains well may be OK. Ask an engineer would be best.